# Remove Back Versions of Ubuntu

Tags: disk, disk-usage

While installing the most recent version of the kernel, I ran out of disk space. How do I go back and delete all of the old versions of the kernel that are occupying my disk

Comment: There are lot of ways to delete old kernels.read the following 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Answer (score 0):

I believe a `sudo apt-get autoremove` will help you with that and `sudo apt-get autoclean`

If you are not using something older then 12.04

Answer (score 0):

If those kernels are selected for manual installation (which is likely since "`apt-get upgrade`" doesn't install them automatically, you need to issue "`apt-get install`" on them manually), "`apt-get autoremove`" won't help.

In this case:

```
dpkg --get-selections linux\*
```

Look for installed packages belonging to the older kernel, then issue "apt-get remove" on them.
For example:

```
apt-get remove linux-headers-3.11.0-12 linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic
```

Then issue "`apt-get autoclean`" to get rid of cached package files.